SQL count all rows with a value within a range from a join
I am attempting a version of what was answered here: Getting count of rows that have values within a value range MySQL. But, the rows I am trying to count are inside a join, and as far as I can tell, I need to be able to assign the join to an alias, which I can't figure out how to do. FWIW, I'm using duckdb, but there shouldn't be a problem, since it accepts SQL queries.
Say my data is like this:
Table1:



id
val




1
1


2
1


3
3


4
2



Table2:



id
words




1
foo


1
bar


2
baz


3
nu


4
olde



And I want to get the count of all the words within 1 val. I suppose after doing an inner join on identical id's and aggregating, the result should look like this:
Joined and counted table:



id
val
words
cnt




1
1
foo
4


1
1
bar
4


2
1
baz
4


3
3
nu
2


4
2
olde
5



Analogizing from the original question, my query is as follows. Note that I have bracketed the INNER JOIN portion in an attempt to assign it to a variable/alias so I can refer to it during the LEFT JOIN:
SELECT
    id,
    val,
    words,
    COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM (Table1
    INNER JOIN Table2
    ON Table1.id=Table2.id) t1
LEFT JOIN t1 t2
    ON ABS(t1.val - t2.val) <= 1
GROUP BY
    t1.val, t1.id;


Can this also be written as a Correlated Subquery?
with t1 as (
   from Table1 join Table2 using (id)
)
from t1 t2 -- the `t2` alias here makes it a correlated subquery
select
   *,
   (select count(*) from t1 where abs(t1.val - t2.val) <= 1) count


┌───────┬───────┬─────────┬───────┐
│  id   │  val  │  words  │ count │
│ int64 │ int64 │ varchar │ int64 │
├───────┼───────┼─────────┼───────┤
│     1 │     1 │ foo     │     4 │
│     1 │     1 │ bar     │     4 │
│     2 │     1 │ baz     │     4 │
│     3 │     3 │ nu      │     2 │
│     4 │     2 │ olde    │     5 │
└───────┴───────┴─────────┴───────┘


When I used this in my non-toy application, this performed very well. I do not blame @nbk for this (since nbk did not have access to my real life data), but by comparison, nbk's solution was much slower, and it strangely resulted in a table with less than half of the expected records.

DuckDb supports CTE so you an process first t1 and use that as source for your calculation
WITH t1 AS
  ( SELECT t1.id, t1.val,t2.words
  FROM Table1 t1
    INNER JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t1.id=t2.id) 
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.val,
    t1.words,
    COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM t1 
LEFT JOIN t1 t2
    ON ABS(t1.val - t2.val) <= 1
GROUP BY
    t1.val, t1.id,t1.words;





id
val
words
cnt




1
1
foo
4


1
1
bar
4


2
1
baz
4


3
3
nu
2


4
2
olde
5




For the sake of readability, should I be concerned with the apparent re-use of the variable t1 at multiple points?

t1 from the cte is ignired in the select below, you can name the tales as you like the cte name has tp be the same as in the select below

For the uninitiated (like me), CTE = common table expression https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/query_syntax/with.html
